# 'card' object has no attribute 'get' Django

Tags: python, django

I have a problem it always shows me this error msg can't open the page 'katalog' (photo bottom of the post)

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class card(models.Model):
    titulli = models.CharField(max_length= 30, null=False)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length= 60, null=False)
    qmimi = models.IntegerField( null=True)
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import card

# Create your views here.
def katalog(request, id):
    lista = card.objects.order_by('titulli')
    param = {
        'listaC': lista
    }
    return HttpResponse('Hello Katalog', param)
```

[Error msg on web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyL9T.png)

Comment: It does not look like this calls the given view, since the view you show here has an `id` parameter.

Comment: With django-toolbar you can drilldown the errors into the LocalVars, there you can find where "card" is called, and what it represents. Also a friendly suggestion to Capitalize your class names.

Comment: Can you please show us the .get() query you are running...